# Why isn't this inferred automatically?

Tags: c#, generics, inferred-type

Up until now, C# inferrence has always worked well for me. I have created a test example to simplify the case.

```
class Parent
{
    public void InferrenceTesting<T>() where T : Parent
    {

    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public void Test()
    {
        //this line gives me a compiler error : The type arguments for method 'Parent.InferrenceTesting<T>()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
        this.InferrenceTesting();
    }
}
```

I have read quite a lot on inferrence, but I am clueless as of why this doesn't work.

Comment: The compiler has nothing to infer from.  The _method_ is generic, not the _class_, so there's no information to tell the compiler what the type of `T` should be.

Comment: try with a parameter, as @DStanley stated compiler has nothing to infer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inference of generic method *type arguments* to the method *type parameters* proceeds by making inferences based on the relationships between the *formal arguments* and the *formal parameters*.

Your method has zero formal arguments and zero formal parameters, so no inferences are made.

Note that in particular **inferences are never made from generic parameter constraints**. Constraints are not part of the *signature* of a method and inference concerns itself with signatures. Rather, constraints are checked *after* type inference has succeeded. If you're expecting some sort of inference to be made from your `where` clause, your expectation is mistaken.

> I have read quite a lot on inference, but I am clueless as of why this doesn't work.

You may wish to read my blog articles on type inference if this subject interests you. They may be more accurate than some of the other articles you've read on this subject; I occasionally see misinformation out there. From my current blog:

https://ericlippert.com/category/csharp/type-inference/

And my former Microsoft blog:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/type-inference/

In particular, see

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/

The comments to that blog are quite interesting. If you've ever wanted to see like a hundred people tell me that I'm wrong, the design is wrong, the implementation is wrong, well, that's the place to go.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing it can use to infer the type from. You've said that `T` has to be a type of `Parent` but since you're not passing a parameter of that type (which the compiler can use to infer the type) you'll have to explicitly name the type.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has no information to infer from - you need a parameter or some other information to tell the compiler what `T` should be in order to infer it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in this, but I think there is *nothing* to infer *from*.

The simple fact that this method is declared in a `Parent` derivate has nothing to do with it.

You need an argument of type `T` for that method so that the compiler has something from which he can infere what should be used as `T`.

In your call, `T` **does not need** to be either `Parent` or `Child`. It can be *anything* as long as it inherits from `Parent`.